# How to pass string,int,char and print them when we are using zend function in php?

Tags: php, visual-c++, php-extension

I am trying to create php extension in which I pass string, int, char to my .cpp file. My zend function in .cpp file is like this:

```
#define PHP_COMPILER_ID  "VC9"

#include "php.h"


ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html);

zend_function_entry use_functions[] = 
{
    ZEND_FE(use_html, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry use_html_module_entry = 
{
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "Use Html",
    use_functions,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "1.0.0-tutorial",
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(use_html);

ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html)
{
     int useHtml;
     char *ch;
     int a=10,b=120,c;
     if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "/", &useHtml) == FAILURE)
     {
         E_ERROR;
         return;
     }
     c=a+b;
     php_printf("sum is",&useHtml);
     php_printf("This string  is %d :" +  useHtml );
     if(useHtml==1)
     {
         php_printf("\n This string uses <a href='#'>Html</a>");
     }
     else
     {
         php_printf("This string does not Html");
     }

     return;
}
```

and php code:

```
<?php

use_html(1);
//use_html("hi"); for string passing
?>
```

**But this does not work. How to pass from php and how to print in zend function?**

Error is like this:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: use_html() expects parameter 1 to be unknown, integer given in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  138008  {main}( )   ..\test.php:0
2   0.0006  138352  use_html ( )    ..\test.php:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this part:

```
if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "/", &useHtml) == FAILURE)
```

You must specify the expected argument type where "/" is.
For accepting every type, you could use "z". But take a look at [README.PARAMETER_PARSING_API file](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=README.PARAMETER_PARSING_API;h=25a41096cf2ec4d9c3ff75f4f3b2bd92e9118f26;hb=refs/heads/master), so to access the char*, long, double values, you must to use a macro or just convert the value to string, for such check out [the documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php).

Comment: I tried with "s" for string, "l" for long but even it creates same problem!

Comment: How are you loading the module? Even the error message still the same?

Comment: thanks for reply. I am loading the module from test.php file. I have created .dll and linking with it! When I take Long int and pass  use_html(1); int valeus, then it works fine, but when I print it, it gives some garbage value. i tried printing using php_printf("This string  is %d :" +  useHtml );, php_printf("This string  is %ld :" +  useHtml ); but gives same garbage value!

Comment: Suppose I have long l;
  char *s;
  int s_len;
  zval *param;
  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "lsz",
                            &l, &s, &s_len, &param) == FAILURE) {
      return;
  }

and then I want to print each element, how can I do?

Comment: 'php_printf("This string is %d :" + useHtml );' ? Do you mean 'php_printf("This string is %d :", useHtml );', right?
You coul check out the php_var_dump() source to figure out how to handle the types through a zval pointer: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/var.c#87

Comment: After I tool s for char *, l for long int it was giving error! problem was something different when I checked error log! I took VC6 in header, but as I am using visual studio 2010 it might not be supporting vc6. I just changed it to VC9 then it started working fine!